# Set cookie to HttpContext response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have tried many different ways to add a cookie to a `HttpContext.Current.Response` with no luck. The browser does not see the cookie that I am adding. Help Please!

Here is my API Controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string username, string password)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

     //This does not work
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ACA-Cookie", "This better work!");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
    cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    cookie.Path = "/";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);

    //This does not work  
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return Ok(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my scenario, I use Angular JS and Web API. However, I use ASP.Net MVC Login to authenticate user.

Basically, user logins at ASP.Net MVC page which uses **ASP.Net Identity**. Once authentication is successful, I redirect to MVC **SPA** (Single Page Application); it maintains Authenticated Cookie every time you request Web API.

If you want to use pure Web API call without MVC, I suggest you to look at **Token Based Authorization** which is a lot easier and better than responding a cookie from Web API.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind WebAPI is based on REST (stateless) and cookies are a way to maintain state. The two concepts really are at odds with one another. If you would like to use cookies, you could consider using ASP.net MVC instead as you could still return serialized data in a framework more suited for state.

Comment: That helps alot!
Would you suggest to use an mvc controller just for the login to set the cookie for the remainder of the requests?

Comment: In my company we developed web api in .Net with Rest and Basic Authentication. Credentials are passed in HTTP request header.

Comment: Agree with derloopkat that the credentials can also be passed in the request header to the WebAPI controller. Using REST, however, it is common to require authentication with every request (to remain stateless).

Comment: I only want to use credentials one time and then use the cookie to authenticate the remainder of the session.

Comment: I'd consider building an MVC application in that case - the framework is better suited for state. REST is meant to forget about the client once the response is sent. This doesn't mean you can't do it in WebAPI, but in my experience, maintaining state in REST is more difficult to implement.